# guessesTaken variable and the for statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning programming with the book: Invent your own computer games with Python.
Here is the code that I am going to refer to. (Python 3.4)

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1,20)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

for guessesTaken in range(6):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess < number-1:
        print('Your guess is too low.')

    if guess > number+1:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
        
    if guess == number + 1:
        print('Close bruh!')

    if guess == number - 1:
        print('Almost!')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken + 1)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number + '.')
```

The book created a variable guessesTaken = 0. But if you run the program it doesn't matter what value you assign to guessesTaken at the beginning. It is as if Python forgets about it when the execution reaches the for statement. I can just as well omit the guessesTaken variable.

If it is true that Python forgets about the assignment statement for the variable, guessesTaken, then Python must use the guessesTaken variable next to the for statement to store the amount of loops that have been completed so that you can print it out for the user.
But the program prints the amount of guessesTaken + 1, so it means that Python counts the first loop as 0.

If all this is true, is it then always so that the variable next to a for statement is going to be the place where Python stores the amount of loops taken ? (as an integer)

Sorry, I started to sound like a Boolean data type :-)

Comment: I think your understanding is pretty much correct. Basically range function will return a list(for simplicity sake considering it is python2. In python3 it is an iterable. But you can imagine list.) which starts with 0. So in your case [0,1,2,3,4,5]. And the variable you mentioned in the for statement will be assigned each of these values in each loop. So at the end of loop it will have a value of 5 it completed all loops. Technically you don't need to assign guessesTaken = 0 at the beginning I guess

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the original assignment of `guessTaken` is over written by `guessTaken` the for loop definition.

The variable in the for loop (in your case `guessTaken`) takes the values of the elements in the iterator itis looping over (in your case `range(6)`)

In your case, `range(6)` returns the iterator `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` so `guessTaken` is 0, then 1, then 2 and so on up to 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand better now.